# How to flatten a jsonb array and return it in a table?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I've tried all sorts of methods to get from this:

```
    qualif_id    |                                                                    qualif_assessment_formats
-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 QL0000000000007 |
 QL0000000000008 |
 QL0000000000009 |
 QL0000000000001 | [{"af_sum": 420, "af_branch": "BR0000000000005", "af_currency": "EUR", "af_app_deadline": "2023-04-22 12:00:00", "af_acquire_datetime": "2023-04-22 14:00:00"}]
```

to this:

```
    qualif_id    |   qualif_assessment_formats
-----------------+-------------------------------
 QL0000000000007 |
 QL0000000000008 |
 QL0000000000009 |
 QL0000000000001 | ["BR0000000000005"]
```

Speaking simply, looking for an analogue of the flatMap function in JavaScript. Like `Array.flatMap(x => x.af_branch)`.

I tried jsonb_to_recordset and jsonb_populate_recordset, though it does not seem to work without the REPEAT function in PostgreSQL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Postgres 12 or later, you can use a JSON path function:

```
select qualif_id,
       jsonb_path_query_array(qualif_assessment_formats, '$[*].af_branch')
from the_table;
```